# How to send concurrent requests to different webservices using spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous

How to send multiple rest / soap requests to different web services. my code so far is sending requests in following order:

```
 webservice1(); //restful
 webservice2(); //soap
 webservice3(); //soap
 webservice4();//soap
 webservice5();//restful
 webservice6();//soap
 webservice7();//restful
```

As shown above, it calls methods respectively, so at first webservice1 sends its request receives it response then webservice 2  will be able to do the same so on so forth.

I need to know how to make them send their requests all at once and whichever receives its response put that in its respective object.

**One of the methods**

```
  public void webservice1(){
     RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                Map<String, String> vars = new HashMap<String, String>();
                vars.put("user", "username");
                vars.put("key", "password");
                vars.put("fl", "po");
                AvailabilityResponse flightResults = restTemplate
                        .getForObject(
                                "http://example.com/availabilityRequest?user={user}&key={key}&fl_type={fl}",
                                AvailabilityResponse.class, vars);
                System.err.println(">>"
                        + flightResults.getFlightList().get(0).getFlightOptions()
                                .getFlightOption().size());

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `Thread`

```
Runnable run = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            webservice1();
        }
    };
Thread t1 = new Thread(run).start();
```

Comment: Is not there any specific feature of Spring/Spring-MVC to help?

Comment: You can check spring @async anno task